# Check if switch from SettingsActivity is on

Tags: android, preferencefragment

How can I check in my MainActivity if the on/off switch is on in the SettingsActivity. I want to check if the switch is on and if it is, I want to do something. How do I do this so that this preference is saved and will be the same when you restart the app?

Here is a part of my SettingsActivity with a switch

```
static int audio;
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static class GeneralPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_text"));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_list"));

        Preference switchPref = (Preference) findPreference("audio_switch");

        switchPref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object o) {

                boolean isOn = (boolean) o;

                if (isOn) {
                    audio = 1;


                }else{
                    audio = 0;

                }
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually do the following:

To save your setting
(Put this in a save() method you call when you click a button or something in your settings activity)

```
SharedPreferences options = 
getSharedPreferences("optionsPreference", 
contextOfSettings.MODE_PRIVATE);
options.edit().putString("key", "value").apply();
```

In order to do this you need to add this in your settings activity

As a global variable in settings

```
public static Context contextOfSettings;
```

And this method in your onCreate of settings

```
@Override
protected void onCreate {
contextOfSettings = getApplicationContext();
}
```

And import it in your main activity by typing context of settings somewhere and then import it by pressing alt+enter
Like this:

```
import com.SettingsActivity.contextOfSettings;
```

Then you can get your saved value (which will still be saved even if you close your app) with this in your on create of your MainActivity

```
SharedPreferences options = getSharedPreferences("optionsPreference", contextOfSettings.MODE_PRIVATE);
String savedValue = options.getString("key", "defaultValue");
```

This String can have the values true and false which you can set with checkBox.isChecked() in combination with an if-statement

Comment: Where do I put the code to save my setting? Anywhere I put it in SettingsActivity it always makes contextOfSettings red. I neither know where to put the second code. Anywhere I put this in SettingsActivity it underlines @Override with a red color saying Annotation are not allowed here.

Comment: The context should be a global variable, and you set the value in the onCreate method. And make sure to import android.content.Context;

Comment: Or if your question is "where should I put the code to save my values?", I would make a button which calls a new method save() which retrieves the switch values and puts them in the sharedPreference

Comment: All I want is check with an if statement if the switch in SettingsActivity is on, that's all, I'm a noob at coding and I don't know where to put all the code, it always makes something red

Comment: I have edited my post and tried to explain where to put everything

Comment: It did not work for me, it still makes contextOfSettings red. Furthermore you did not explain exactly where I should put the code in settingsActivity. This file also has multiple onCreate thingies. And when I try to  import com.SettingsActivity.contextOfSettings; it makes everything lightgrey, and it makes SettingsActivity red. The error is unused import statement.

Comment: I put contextOfSettings = getApplicationContext(); here @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        contextOfSettings = getApplicationContext();
        setupActionBar();
    }

Comment: }
    }
    public static Context contextOfSettings;
}

Comment: 1. The code in your settings activity should be in the normal onCreate as you did (and I told). 2. I would place a global variable at the beginning of my code, not af the end. 3. It could be that the error is caused because contextOfSettings is not yet defined if you start mainActivity before ever launching settingsActivity

Answer (score 0):

You are saving correctly the preference value, even you are **returning true** from your `onPreferenceChangeListener` to store the new value.

---

```
 Preference switchPref = (Preference) findPreference("audio_switch");

    switchPref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object o) {

            boolean isOn = (boolean) o;

            if (isOn) {
                audio = 1;
            }else{
                audio = 0;
            }

                 //* Set true to update the state of the Preference with the new value!
                return true;
            }

        });
    }
```

The value is saved correctly when you close the application, **if you want to check the value you can read it from the preference**:

```
   //Check the current value in preference.
   SharedPreferences switchPrefStatus = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
   boolean switchPrefValue = switchPrefStatus.getBoolean("audio_switch", false);
   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Current value: " + switchPrefValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Here is a complete example of [PreferenceFragment with PreferenceFragment](https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-SwitchPreference):

[image]

Comment: Where do I have to pasteSharedPreferences switchPrefStatus = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
   boolean switchPrefValue = switchPrefStatus.getBoolean("audio_switch", false);
   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Current value: " + switchPrefValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  I do not have a fragmentactivity or how its called. Just settings activity and Mainactivity. WHere should I paste the code

Comment: @100Awesome when you app starts, in the onCreate() method of your launcher activity :)

Comment: when I paste that code in it makes the two getActivity words red .

Comment: your class must extend Activity or AppCompatActivity, is your class an Activity, see the example: https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-SwitchPreference/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/jorgesys/preferencefragment/MainActivity.java

Comment: That is not what I want, I want the switch to be in the SettingsActivity when you click on the 3 dots and go to general, not at MainActivity. All I need is something to retrieve the variable audio from SettingsActivity and look in Mainactivity if audio = 1

Comment: you are not  retrieving the variable (preference value) audio from SettingsActivity, you must retrieve the value from the preference.

Comment: But how do I do that, the code in your MainActivity creates a switch for me which is not what I want.